# I'm making a mod for Everlasting summer, my code constantly gives the error Line is indented

Tags: renpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQGKU.png)I'm new to Ren'Py and I can't solve the problem with Line is indented,he constantly complains about the 9th line, but at the same time I don't know what I've tried a lot here, but nothing helped

I searched the Internet but did not find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- I don't think you need $ at the beginning of your label definition.  "label" is a Ren'Py statement, $ is used to let Ren'Py know you're doing a Python statement.
- label should be lowercase. Programs are just picky about that type of thing.
- You need a : at the end of your label. This lets Ren'Py/Python know that you're starting a "block", which is indented.

In the end, it should look like this:

```
label Durka_1:
    scene bg image2 with dissolve2
```

The Ren'Py docs entry on labels has a lot of helpful info on this stuff as well: https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/label.html